# How to search in VSCode while ignoring whitespace without having to manually use regular expressions every time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an angular app that uses Bootstrap 5 and so a lot of my development is inspecting an element in the browser and then identifying the file that needs updating.

I'll inspect an element and find something unique about it for example a class of "ps-4 pe-4" and so I'll jump into vscode and perform a global search for that. However, because my code is formatted across multiple lines, with a huge amount of whitespace between each class name I can't find the file I need to.

I know I can use a regular expression such as `ps-4\s*pe-4` but when I'm searching for something like, `ps-4 pe-4 mb-0 g-0 h4 text-uppercase` it's a long task.

Note: There are multiple people working in this repo all with different HTML prettifiers and formatters. This cannot be changed.

My ultimate goal is to have a "Ignore duplicate whitespace for this search" button toggle next to the search box.

Comment: silly workaround: two-layer regex: open a new tab, write `ps-4 pe-4 mb-0 g-0 h4 text-uppercase`, then find and replace spaces with `\s*`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this asked before so I added some functionality to an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), that might help.

What you or an extension cannot do is add a button toggle to the Search/Find widgets, so only an extension can approximate the functionality you are looking for.

Try this keybinding in your `keybindings.json` (or it could be a setting which creates a command which will show up in the Command Palette):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "runInSearchPanel",
  "args": {
    
    // all these versions of find work

    // "find": "ps-4 pe-4 mb-0 g-0 h4 text-uppercase",     // hard-coded find

    // "find": "${CLIPBOARD}",           // copy the text

    "find": "${selectedText}",           // just select the text, see demo #1

    // "find": "${getFindInput}",        // paste the text into an input box, demo #2
    
               // the input can be mixed with other pre-existing text 
    // "find": "someTextHere ${getFindInput} OtherText",

    "ignoreWhiteSpace": true,  
    "isRegex": true,
    "triggerSearch": true,    // optional
  }
}
```

- Demo #1 using `${selectedText}`

[image: ignore white space search across files with selected text]

- Demo #2 using `${getFindInput}`

[image: ignore white search across files with input text]

---

The keybinding can do a lot more - like restrict the searches to previous search results files and much more.